Какую файловую структуру нужно использовать для набора изображений с аннотациями на Hugging Face Hub, чтобы parquet-converter распознал их?
Какую файловую структуру следует использовать на платформе Hugging Face Hub, если у меня, к примеру, есть архив /train.zip с PNG-файлами изображениями и файл /metadata.csv с аннотациями для них, чтобы бот parquet-converter мог автоматически распознать и правильно интерпретировать этот набор данных?

Пример желаемого результата




Официальная документация

Но вне зависимости от того, какое взаимное расположение файлов я использую,

https://huggingface.co/datasets/james-r/so-invalid-image-archive-with-metadata-1

/train.zip
/metadata.csv

или
/train/train.zip
/metadata.csv

я получаю исключение:
Cannot load the dataset split (in streaming mode) to extract the first rows.
Error code:   StreamingRowsError
Exception:    ValueError
Message:      One or several metadata.csv were found, but not in the same directory or in a parent directory of zip://1.png::hf://datasets/[user]/[repo-name]@[hash]/train/train.zip.
Traceback:    Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/src/services/worker/src/worker/job_runners/split/first_rows.py", line 322, in compute
                  compute_first_rows_from_parquet_response(
                File "/src/services/worker/src/worker/job_runners/split/first_rows.py", line 88, in compute_first_rows_from_parquet_response
                  rows_index = indexer.get_rows_index(
                File "/src/libs/libcommon/src/libcommon/parquet_utils.py", line 640, in get_rows_index
                  return RowsIndex(
                File "/src/libs/libcommon/src/libcommon/parquet_utils.py", line 521, in __init__
                  self.parquet_index = self._init_parquet_index(
                File "/src/libs/libcommon/src/libcommon/parquet_utils.py", line 538, in _init_parquet_index
                  response = get_previous_step_or_raise(
                File "/src/libs/libcommon/src/libcommon/simple_cache.py", line 590, in get_previous_step_or_raise
                  raise CachedArtifactError(
              libcommon.simple_cache.CachedArtifactError: The previous step failed.
              
              During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
              
              Traceback (most recent call last):
                File "/src/services/worker/src/worker/utils.py", line 96, in get_rows_or_raise
                  return get_rows(
                File "/src/libs/libcommon/src/libcommon/utils.py", line 197, in decorator
                  return func(*args, **kwargs)
                File "/src/services/worker/src/worker/utils.py", line 73, in get_rows
                  rows_plus_one = list(itertools.islice(ds, rows_max_number + 1))
                File "/src/services/worker/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 1389, in __iter__
                  for key, example in ex_iterable:
                File "/src/services/worker/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/iterable_dataset.py", line 234, in __iter__
                  yield from self.generate_examples_fn(**self.kwargs)
                File "/src/services/worker/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/packaged_modules/folder_based_builder/folder_based_builder.py", line 376, in _generate_examples
                  raise ValueError(
              ValueError: One or several metadata.csv were found, but not in the same directory or in a parent directory of zip://1.png::hf://datasets/[user]/[repo-name]@[hash]/train/train.zip.

Что я делаю не так?

Судя по всему, это ошибка пакета datasets.
На сегодняшний день эта проблема решается приведением файлов metadata.csv к metadata.jsonl.

Пример распознаваемой структуры файлов

